# VC# Studio Setup Project 2010: Set Prerequisite to .Net 2.0 or HIGHER?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, setup-project

guys!

Is there any way to set required .Net Framework in a more universal way? 
I mean to set 2.0 if we install app under WinXp and 4.0 if we are under Vista or Win7?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'd have to create two separate installers for both OS targets. That would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to set the requirements depending on the target OS ? You want to set your requirements depending on ... your requirements ! 
If you are using .net 4 features, and the `target framework` in your project is defined as being .Net 4, the required framework will be 4.

IF you arent using `.Net 4` features, in your project properties, just set the `client target` to
`.Net 2.0` for example.

You can do so by right clicking your project, properties, then under the build tab, click on `Advanced options/settings`, and at the bottom you can see the `target framework`, which you can change.

Edit : Obviously, in the `VSI` you can change the requirements, but by default, it uses the the "real" requirements. If you want to change the requirements in the `Visual Studio Installer project`, right click on that `project` -> `properties` -> `Required Components`